# Is it possible to dequeue and queue in same transaction

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a message a want to dequeue then right after its dequeued I want to queue another message to a different queue. I want to do all this in the same transaction. is this possible with rabbitmq or any other queueing service?

Comment: Dequeuing messages based on what condition? You may give a try on TTL, once it's expired it will automatically move to DLX. Alternative to this you can write an erlang plugin if you wanted to change the behavior on the way the messages are queuing.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to what you want with RabbitMQ is:

Use [acks and publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

- You receive a message and do not `ack` it.
- Send your reply message.
- Wait for `confirm` from the broker.
- Once `confirm` had arrived, `ack` initial message.

But then, consider this failure situation:

- Initial message received
- Reply message sent
- Your service failed before ACKing initial message
- When your service is back, it will receive the initial message again

So you will need to use some deduplication mechanism etc.